# Changing the Color of the Dynamically loaded Buttons onclick

Tags: android

Android:  I have created dynamic buttons based on my arraylist size,Lets consider 10 buttons. When a button is clicked, the color of the button will change to grey. When another one is clicked, the color of the previous button should be reset to the default color.

```
    boolean iscolor = true;
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.total_count);
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int j =1;j<=datalist.size()/2;j++) {
        final Button btn = new Button(getContext());
        final int id_ = j;
        btn.setText("" + j);
        btn.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        btn.setMaxWidth(5);
        btn.setId(id_);
        btn.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        btn.setBackgroundColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkBlue));
        linearLayout.addView(btn, params);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                   if (!iscolor ) {
                   btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DarkBlue));

                     iscolor =true;
                  }
                 else
                  {

                    btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
                    iscolor = false;

                 }


    }});
```

How to restore the color of the previous clicked Button in Android.

Comment: store the previously-clicked button in a variable

Comment: i suggest you to make a map which holds the button index and its view. It'll ease your logic part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 /* you need to have already stored buttons in a data structure, something like : List<Button> btns; */
             for(Button b : btns){
                  if(b.getId() == v.getId(){ b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray)); } else{ b.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourdefaultcolor)); }   //no need for isColor variable


}});
linearLayout.addView(btn, params);
```

Comment: Have added the linearLayout.addView(btn, params); outside the onclick function still not working

Comment: In your `onClick` method, when a button is clicked you need to set all others buttons colors to default (not only setting the clicked button color as you are doing)

Comment: Thank you so Much.Its Working Now

Comment: Happy to hear that.